# Killing/suspending a kernel thread on windows 10

Tags: c++, multithreading, kernel, kill, suspend

I'm currently working on a project where I must kill or suspend a thread running in kernel mode on windows 10. I've looked everywhere but I can't seem to find any answers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why?  I think you need to give some more details of what you are trying to achieve.  (Killing a thread is almost never a good idea.  Killing one in kernel mode sounds even more dangerous.)

Comment: Note that a kernel thread can be a "stolen" user mode thread and killing that will also kill the user mode thread.  Anyway you are going to have to write a kernel mode driver and user-mode <--> kernel-mode communications.  Which is too bigger topic for OS so voting to close as too broad.